# Keep Xcode 5/6/7 on the same machine

Tags: ios, xcode

So we need to distribute some library to our clients, who could use any of versions 5, 6, or 7 of Xcode. I am using OSX 10.9.5, and I can keep 5 and 6 side by side.

We plan to add Xcode 7. But Apple won't let me download 7 in 10.9.5. And I heard online that El Capitan doesn't support Xcode older than 7.

So what's the best strategy to keep all 5/6/7?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Xcode 7 can be installed on Yosemite(Above 10.10) versions so strategy would be :

1. Create a partition on your mac, install yosemite in that new partition which you created and then you can install Xcode 7
2. In the other partition you can have mavericks or below versions to have Xcode 6 and Xcode 5